# I built my rails app with sqlite and without specifying any db field sizes, Is my app now foobared for production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I've been following a lot of good tutorials on building rails apps but I seem to be missing the whole specifying and validating db field sizes part. I love not needing to have to think about it when roughing out an app (I would have never done this with a PHP or ASP.net app). However, now that I'm ready to go to production, I think I might have done myself a disservice by not specifying field sizes as I went. My production db will be MySQL. What is the best practice here? Do I need to go through all of my migration files and specify sizes, update all the models with validation, and update all my form partial views with input max widths? or am I missing a critical step in my development process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're fine. Launching a web application is a process and the first step is to expose your app to the user and get the ball rolling. Refinements can follow. You are NOT fubared.

In general, i've NOT specified max field length's for each and every single field. Specify it only on those fields where it makes sense otherwise the default is good.

You're not making applications that come into play as a matter of life and death are you? If yes, then i'm not qualified to answer, i guess :)